# Warning: There were multiply-defined labels

Tags: cross-referencing, warnings

I got a "LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels", and I know what it means but my document is pretty big and it has various files. So, how can I find the multiply-defined label?

I am using TeXShop in MacOS.

This is the whole warning (I believe):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bibliography
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(./Thesis.bbl [29] [30] [31] [32] [33] [34] [35]) [36] (./Thesis.aux)
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.
 )
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The log message you quoted is a sort of "summary" of earlier, more detailed warnings, telling you exactly which references are undefined/multiply defined. Scroll up through the log file and you should find more detailed messages that look like the one below:

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `foo' multiply defined.
```

Comment: Using `grep "multiply defined" master.log` worked like a charm for me. Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't occur if it is a label in the TOC (or doesn't for me)

Comment: @DavidL maybe `grep "multiply defined" master.log | uniq` in addition?

Answer (score 22):

There are ways to find duplicate labels in complex documents that have not been mentioned in the other answers. To show how they work I will use a simple (non-complex) test case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\label{foo}

\section{Section 2}
\label{foo}

\end{document}
```

### RefTeX

[RefTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/reftex.html) can find duplicate labels with the function [`reftex-find-duplicate-labels`](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex/Commands.html#Commands) which produce a list of all duplicate labels in the document. To use it simply do `M-x reftex-find-duplicate-labels`. When doing this on the file with the test case it opens a new buffer with the following content:

```
                MULTIPLE LABELS IN CURRENT DOCUMENT:
 Move point to label and type `r' to run a query-replace on the label
 and its references.  Type `q' to exit this buffer.

 LABEL               FILE
 -------------------------------------------------------------
foo
    ~/test/test.tex
    ~/test/test.tex
```

### Perl

[As noted by Walt Mankowski one can use a Perl one-liner to find duplicate labels](http://www.mawode.com/blog/blog/2012/03/21/finding-duplicate-latex-labels/). The one-liner is as follows:

```
perl -nE 'say $1 if /(\\label[^}]*})/' *.tex | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

To use it open a terminal and `cd` to the directory of the document you want to check for duplicate labels in and then execute the one-liner. The output for the test case is as follows:

```
      2 \label{foo}
```

---

Relatedly you may also want to [check for unused labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25743/5701).

Comment: This RefTex advice is worth gold.

Comment: the perl one-liner just saved my life :-)

Comment: My problem is that my work is scattered in several directories. Is there  a version of this one-liner that scans a directory? I know nothing of Perl.

Comment: I'd like to extend that oneliner for tex documents which `include` or `input` tex files from subdirectories: `perl -nE 'say $1 if /(\\label[^}]*})/' $(find . -name '*.tex' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g') | sort | uniq -c | sort -n` See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) on using SED for replacing newlines.

Answer (score 18):

Besides looking into the .log file, the [showlabels](http://ctan.org/pkg/showlabels) package could help you if you would like to check the labels in the output.

To check the input, you could open a terminal and grep for labels:

```
grep label filename.tex
```

This gives you a compact overview.

Comment: Solved by deleting my .aux file, but this answer deserves a +1.

Comment: grep label{ filename.tex gives only the label tags.

Answer (score 2):

Extension: I just finished a debug tracking down multiply-defined label but only one instance of creating that label.  Turns out if you have a table break across pages and a *first head* is not defined, multiple instances of the label occur.

```
\begin{longtable}{c}
\caption{my text \label{tab:mine}}\\
Title\\
\endfirsthead
\caption{my text, continued}\\
Title\\
\endhead
blah\\
.
.
.
blah\\
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: This will be reported in the log file just as in Seamus' answer.

Comment: @AndrewSwann The label itself was reported as being multiply defined, true. But it does not say _why_ in the log file, especially when there is only one instance of `\label` in the tex file. This answer explains why which is how I got rid of it. +1 to @KC7HP.

Comment: Your code in a minimal document does _not_ produce such a warning (even with longer table contents that spread over several pages).  Yes, you should read the `longtable` documentation carefully before placing the `\label` command.