# How can I get LaTeX to warn about unreferenced figures and unused labels in general?

Tags: cross-referencing, warnings

When writing documents, I consider it to be necessary that all figures and tables are referenced (`\ref`) in the text, whether or not I've remembered to `\label` them. LaTeX does not currently warn if a figure or table is not referenced. Is there a way to ensure that this is flagged up as a warning?

Note that I am specifically concerned about figures and tables, not chapter or section headings; it will be no good looking just at `\label`s that don't have an associated `\ref`.

In other words, it should report `boo` and not report `bla` in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{BLA}\label{bla}
\section{BOO}\label{boo}
In Section~\ref{bla} we do something.
\end{document}
```

Comment: for anyone wondering about `cleveref`, see [Making refcheck work with cleveref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87610)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use the package **[refcheck](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcheck)**. It is

> Intended to check references in a document, looking for numbered but
>   unlabelled equations, for labels which are not used in the text, for
>   unused bibliography references.

Note that it checks for labels that are not used in the text *but not* for tables and figures that are not labelled. Thus if you got a table or figure without a label you'll not get warned. If you compile the following you'll get a demonstration of its core features (the idea for this is from [the package's excellent demo](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/refcheck/refdemo.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}% Labelled and referred to
1+1=2
\end{equation}

\ref{eq:1}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}% Labelled but not referred to
1-1=0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}% Not labelled nor referred to
1+1=0
\end{equation}

\begin{table}[h]
\center
\begin{tabular}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Numbers}\label{tab:1}% Labelled but not referred to
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h]\label{fig:1}% Labelled but not referred to
\caption{Foo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The last two equations will be marked by "?" in the output because they're not labelled *and* referred to. The table and figure will be marked by "?" because they're labelled but not referred to. Also the .log file will contain:

```
 Unused label `eq:2' on page 1
 Unlabelled equation (3) on page 1
 Unused label `tab:1' on page 1
 Unused label `fig:1' on page 1
```

Note that refcheck should be loaded *after* the ams packages and the hyperref package.

Relatedly you may also want to [check for duplicate labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69086/5701).

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the quick and great answer.

Comment: @BillCheatham I've updated my answer with a better example and a note on it not warning for figures and tables that are not labelled (it only warns for tables and figures that are labelled but not referred to).

Comment: Does this work with `\autoref`?