# Is there a way to force LaTeX to issue a warning if a figure is never referenced?

Tags: cross-referencing, warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get LaTeX to warn about unreferenced figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25742/how-can-i-get-latex-to-warn-about-unreferenced-figures)

In my document I have several figures, most of which I created references for (using `\ref{}`) immediately after I placed them into the document. However, I had a few figures that I forgot to reference in the document, leaving some figures "hanging" without any citation, which is a mistake on my part and must be corrected.

So, my questions is:

**Is there a way to force latex to issue a warning if a figure is never referenced?**

Comment: Are all figures labeled?

Comment: Yes, in my case all of the figures are labeled.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`refcheck`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcheck) package might be useful here.

The following MWE has a figure that is not referenced, so the `refcheck` puts a warning in your pdf with `?` surrounding it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \rule{20pt}{30pt}
 \caption{}
 \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As soon as you reference the figure, the `?` will be removed. Note that this method does rely on each figure having a label.

Note that I have demonstrated `refcheck` with a `figure`, but it works in the same way for *anything* that has a label (`table`, `chapter`, `equation`, etc).

Comment: That's a neat package I'd never heard of.  Thanks!

Comment: That's quite useful. However, is there a way to have `refcheck` loaded, and not have the `<fig:myfig>` in the margin, once the figure is referenced.

Comment: @PeterGrill Good question, not sure! I usually just comment out `%\usepackage{refcheck}` when I'm done checking

Answer (score 8):

Here's a hand-made solution:

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter

\let\LaTeX@original@label\label
\let\LaTeX@original@ref\ref

\newcommand{\warnunused}{}

\renewcommand{\label}[1]{%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\def\csname warning@#1\endcsname{%
    \typeout{warning: label #1 was not referenced.}}%
  \g@addto@macro\warnunused{%
    \csname warning@#1\endcsname}
  \LaTeX@original@label{#1}}

\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\def\csname warning@#1\endcsname{}
  \LaTeX@original@ref{#1}}

\makeatother
```

and the following directly before `\end{document}`:

```
\warnunused
```

Now on every LaTeX run, for each unreferenced label you get a line

```
warning: label (your label here) was not referenced.
```

on your standard output and in your refwarn.log.

If you prefer the warning directly in your document instead, remove the `\typeout` (and possibly add a `\texttt` around the `#1` and a `\\` at the end) in the warning macro.