# Making refcheck work with cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, refcheck

It seems that `refcheck` does not recognize references made by cleveref:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a & = b \label{eq:a} \\
  c & = d \label{eq:b}
\end{align}

See~\eqref{eq:a}, \cref{eq:b}.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Figure 1}
  \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Figure 2}
  \label{fig:b}
\end{figure}

See Figure~\ref{fig:a}, \cref{fig:b}.

\end{document}
```

Here, `refcheck` marks `eq:b` and `fig:b` as unreferenced.

1. Is there a way to make the two packages work together?
2. Alternatively, are there replacement packages that do work better?
3. If the answer to 1) is yes, can this even be achieved for `\crefrange`?

Comment: Have you tried "Poor man's cleveref" (chapter 10 in [`cleveref`'s docs](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf))? This should be an easy workaround on a Linux or Mac OS X system.

Comment: @user946850 I know that option, but I'm not convinced. As a purist, I don't want to run `sed` scripts in between. And you still have the false positives when using compressed references (`\crefrange`, and `\cref` with several labels).

Answer (score 31):

`refcheck` doesn't know about `\cref` and `\Cref`. We can add a macro that makes the package aware of other reference commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{refcheck}

%%% Infrastructure    
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\refcheckize}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname @@\string#1\endcsname#1%
  \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\csname relax\string#1\endcsname[1]{%
    \csname @@\string#1\endcsname{##1}\wrtusdrf{##1}}%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter#1\csname relax\string#1\endcsname
}
\makeatother
%%%

%%% Now we add the reference commands we want refcheck to be aware of
\refcheckize{\cref}
\refcheckize{\Cref}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a & = b \label{eq:a} \\
  c & = d \label{eq:b}
\end{align}

See~\eqref{eq:a}, \cref{eq:b}.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Figure 1}
  \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Figure 2}
  \label{fig:b}
\end{figure}

See Figure~\ref{fig:a}, \Cref{fig:b}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! But does it work when `\cref`fing multiple labels? And what about `\crefrange` and friends? -- It seems that at least one of the packages should be enhanced to support the other, perhaps both: I imagine a command like `\noref` (provided by `refcheck`) that would simply mark a reference as "used" and could be called by `cleveref`, `autoref`, `nameref`, ...

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately, I use `\cref` almost exclusively for multiple references to employ the compression feature, and in this case your solution obviously won't work. I guess one needs to hook deeper into the packages. Should I ask the `cleveref` author for active support of `refcheck`, or the `refcheck` author (I'm not sure if he is still an active Texie.)?

Comment: @user946850 `refcheck` simply modifies `\ref` and `\pageref` to write `\usedref` in the `.aux` file; the "refcheckized" macros do just the same.

Comment: @mafp I'm afraid that this requires *much* more work.

Comment: @mafp: According to egreg's comment, it seems that there's no need to modify `refcheck`, but `cleveref` (or its author...) should be made aware of that package. The `cleveref` docs suggest that (a) the package is well maintained and (b) the author is not aware of `refcheck` (quick search for "refcheck"). It would definitely be a great improvement for `cleveref`...

Comment: This also works with `\autoref` of `hyperref`.

Comment: @egreg Any updates/thoughts on this after three years? Could not find any tool (like ```chklref```) or package (like ```refcheck```) that supports commands such as ```\Cref{fig:a,fig:b}```. Already wrote the cleveref author.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, nothing I know about.

Comment: Is there a similar incantation that will make refcheck work with \autopageref?

Comment: @Mark Have you tried `\refcheckize{\autopageref}`?

Comment: Yep, no effect as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Mark The problem is that `hyperref` redefines `\ref` and `\pageref` to have a possible `*` after them; you can try out `\ref*{label}` and see it doesn't work. If you don't plan to use `*`-variants of the commands, I think it's possible to make them work. Supporting `*`-variants is not done by `refcheck` anyway.

Comment: @Mark Isn't it easier using `\cpageref`?

Comment: You're right, the star variants don't work. I don't need the star variants though.  And cpageref is from cleveref, right?  I'm not using cleveref.  Should I be?

Comment: \cpageref solves nothing actually; I just tried it.  Only the page number gets a hyperlink, and not the word "page".  If that's what I wanted, there's already good old \pageref :)

Comment: Is there similar magic I can use to get \nameref to work?

Comment: It is indeed possible to get the starred version of `\ref` to work with `refcheck`, e.g. using my quick fix from this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274822/73383 :)

Comment: This was working for me in the past but recently found that I needed an extra pair of curly braces for the reference to be detected properly. This was easy to fix by using `\wrtusdrf` on both: `\wrtusdrf{##1}\wrtusdrf{{##1}}`. I see no harm in putting both, maybe will help someone else with the same issue.

Comment: Des it work with `\autoref`?

Comment: @KcFnMi Did you try with `\refcheckize{\autoref}`?

Comment: Got Undefined control sequence. Whre should I put that command? Is there any documentation for this command? Can't find it on https://mirror-hk.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/refcheck/refdemo.pdf.

Comment: @KcFnMi You did `\usepackage{hyperref}`, didn't you?

Comment: Ok, got it! I would like to have `showrefs` only for unreferenced labels, is it possible?

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same issue, and found it was relatively straightforward to extend egreg's answer to handle extra cases like `\crefrange{eq1}{eq2}` and `\cref{eq1,eq2,eq4}`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\refcheckize}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname @@\string#1\endcsname#1%
  \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\csname relax\string#1\endcsname[1]{%
    \csname @@\string#1\endcsname{##1}\@for\@temp:=##1\do{\wrtusdrf{\@temp}\wrtusdrf{{\@temp}}}}%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter#1\csname relax\string#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand{\refcheckizetwo}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname @@\string#1\endcsname#1%
  \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\csname relax\string#1\endcsname[2]{%
    \csname @@\string#1\endcsname{##1}{##2}\wrtusdrf{##1}\wrtusdrf{{##1}}\wrtusdrf{##2}\wrtusdrf{{##2}}}%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter#1\csname relax\string#1\endcsname
}
\makeatother

\refcheckize{\cref}
\refcheckize{\Cref}
\refcheckizetwo{\crefrange}
\refcheckizetwo{\Crefrange}
```

Credit goes to egreg for the original solution.

### 2016 Edit:

I'm not sure why, but this had stopped working for me at some point. I started getting a lot of errors like this again:

```
Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `{eq:objective}' on input line 30.
```

For whatever reason (maybe a strange interaction of packages) refcheck was expecting an extra pair of curly braces. That is, it expected `\label{eq:objective}` to be paired with `\wrtusdrf{{eq:objective}}`, but the `\refcheckize` commands were only producing `\wrtusdrf{eq:objective}`.

To fix this I have now put a matching `\wrtusdrf{{...}}` along with every `\wrtusdrf{...}` in the macros. This shouldn't have any negative effect provided that you don't differentiate labels solely with curly braces (please don't do that.)

Comment: Works very well. However, the solution doesn't seem to like ```subfigures``` (using the ```subcaption``` package).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with using a little shell script to find unreferenced labels. This has some drawbacks of course, but works very well in my case (document with hundreds of pages):

```
# Helper function to find unreferenced labels, since the chkltex tool and the refcheck package do not support cleveref
# Note: this could show false positives sometimes
echo "Checking for unreferenced labels...";
labels=$(grep -Eo '^[\s]*[^%]+.*label{[^}]+}' $_dir_sources/*.tex|sed -Ee "s/^.*{(.*)}/\1/g")
for label in $labels; do
  found=$(grep -E "ref{[^}]*$label" $_dir_sources/*.tex)
  if [[ -z "$found" ]]; then
    echo "Label '$label' not referenced?";
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

My choice is to write my own `\cref` command.

```
\iffalse
    \usepackage{refcheck}
    \def\crefname#1#2#3{}
    \def\cref#1{\{\getrefs#1,\relax\}}
    \def\getrefs#1,#2\relax{%
        \ref{#1}%
        \ifx\relax#2\relax\else
            , \getrefs#2\relax
        \fi
    }
\else
    \usepackage[capitalise,poorman]{cleveref}
\fi
```

Truning `\iffalse` to `\iftrue` drops the `cleveref` package, and defines `\crefname` and `\cref`.
Then `\refcheck` should work well. (Of course it changes the style of the reference, but it won't change the reference relation.)

Answer (score 0):

Alex's answer did not work for me at first (sed issues the error "char 14: Invalid content of {}
"). I am not a regex expert, so I ended up rewriting the line that finds the labels. So far this works for any type of reference:

```
echo "Checking for unreferenced labels...";
# find all label names
labels=$(grep -oP 'label{[^}]+}' *.tex | sed -e "s/^.*label{//" -e "s/}//")
#echo $labels
# for each label, see if it appears in a ref command (\ref, \cref and others)
for label in $labels; do
   found=$(grep -E "ref{[^}]*$label" *.tex)
if [[ -z "$found" ]]; then
    echo "Label '$label' not referenced";
fi
done
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please explain your "did not work" better, for example showing the resulting error message etc. What did you changed in your given code and why?

Comment: Thanks for your remark, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated Laurent90's answer to

- include .tex files in subfolders
- only consider `\label` as labels so as not to include things like `\fmflabel`
- not include labels that have been commented out (though it will fail to include a label if the label is preceded by `\%` for instance)
- not consider labels referenced if the ref is commented out (though it will give false positives if preceded by `\%` for instance)
- there must be a `,` or `}` right after the label when it is referenced so the label `abc` is not falsely considered referenced if a label `abcd` is referenced

```shell
# remove "-not -iname '*appendix*.tex'" to include appendix files
files=$(find . -iname '*.tex' -not -iname '*appendix*.tex')
labels=$(sed -E "s/^[ \t]*[^%]*\\\label\{([^}]+)\}.*/\1/g;t;d" $files)
for label in $labels; do
grep -Eq "^[ \t]*[^%]*ref{[^}]*$label[},]" $files || echo "Label '$label' not referenced"
done
```