# How to make refcheck work with autoref?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, refcheck

I have just discovered [`refcheck`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcheck) and would love it to bits if my document wasn't full of `\autoref`'s. According to `refcheck`'s documentation, it works with `hyperref` in general, as long as the latter is loaded first, but apparently that doesn't extend to `\autoref`'s (as per MWE below). Is there a way to make the two work together and correctly mark labels as referenced when done so via `\autoref`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}

\autoref{mylabel} is referenced here, so why does refcheck mark it as unreferenced?

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{My  caption}\label{mylabel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I don't actually see anything in the `refcheck` code that does anything special for `hyperref`.  The only thing seems to work is `\ref`.  Commands such as `\ref*` actually give a wrong output with `refcheck` loaded.  For `\autoref` see the final comment on the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87648/15925