# conflict refcheck/subcaption packages for label with underscores

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility, subcaption, refcheck

I found a conflict between the hyperref/subcaption/refcheck packages.

I was using figures with subfigures and subcaptions, enabling the hyperref package for cross referencing in the document without any problems so far.

When I included the refcheck package to check for unused bib items and cross references, it causes problems if I cross link a subfigure using the `\subref{...}` command to a figure label with underscores, eg. `\label{fig:A_A_A}`, in the caption of the figure environment (see MWE with `\subref{fig:A_A_A}`)

It complaings about missing $ as if it would like to put the underscores in math mode.

```
Missing $ inserted [...]
```

Any ideas how to fix this conflict?

---

EDIT:
If I load the refcheck package before the other two packages, the document compiles fine, but then actually the refcheck package functionality is lost, i.e. no warnings about unused references.

---

MWE.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}          %Make hyperlinks available
\usepackage{subcaption}        %Make subfigures available

%commenting out this package restores the working version   
\usepackage{refcheck}          %Warn for unused bibitems

\begin{document}
Figure \ref{fig:A_A} %no problem with the reference here

\begin{figure}[bhpt!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \rule{3cm}{3cm} %dummy for a grafic
    \caption{A subcaption}
    \label{fig:A_A_A} %problematic label for subfigure with underscores
  \end{subfigure}  
  \caption[A short caption]%
          %caption without the subref works without any problems
          %{A long caption without a subref}
          %caption with subref for the label with underscores causes problem
          {A long caption with a subref with underscores \subref{fig:A_A_A}}
  \label{fig:A_A} %no problem with label for figure with underscores
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that `refcheck` isn't really compatible with `hyperref`, because `refcheck` doesn't respect `hyperref`'s starred version of the `\ref` macro (this could be considered a bug with `refcheck`, and should probably be reported to the package maintainer).

When you do `\subref{fig:A_A_A}` it expands to something like this:

```
\hyperref[fig:A_A_A]{%
  \begingroup
    \caption@setoptions{sub}%
    \subcaption@reffmt\p@subref{%
      \ref*{sub@fig:A_A_A}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
```

Note the use of `\ref*` here. It's because `hyperref` overrides the regular `\ref` to use `\hyperref` to produce a hyperlink. `hyperref` therefore also provides `\ref*` as an alternative that does the same as `\ref`, except that it doesn't generate a hyperlink (you can think of `\ref{A}` as the same as `\hyperref[A]{\ref*{A}}`). In the case above, the reference text and the link use different reference labels, hence the use of `\ref*`.

Because `refcheck` overrides `\ref` without regards to `hyperref`'s `\ref*` macro, you basically lose the "capabilities" of the starred version. Hence `\ref*{A}` will now expand as if you'd written `\ref{*}{A}`.

In the case of `\ref*{sub@fig:A_A_A}`, you hence get `\ref{*}{sub@fig:A_A_A}`, which clearly won't work very well. You'll get a warning

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `*' on page 1 undefined on input line XY
```

and since `{sub@fig:A_A_A}` is not an argument to the `\ref` macro, you'll get the normal "underscore error" that you saw.

### EDIT

As a quick-fix, you could use something like this in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{refcheck}{%
    \@ifundefined{hyperref}{}{%
      \let\T@ref@orig\T@ref
      \def\T@ref#1{\T@ref@orig{#1}\wrtusdrf{#1}}%
      \let\@refstar@orig\@refstar
      \def\@refstar#1{\@refstar@orig{#1}\wrtusdrf{#1}}%
      \DeclareRobustCommand\ref{\@ifstar\@refstar\T@ref}%
    }%
  }{}%
}

\makeatother
```

This code restores `hyperref`'s definition of `\ref`, and patches the `\T@ref` (the non-starred version) and the `\@refstar` (the starred version) macros that `hyperref` uses.