# Refcheck and \autopageref not getting along

Tags: refcheck, autoref

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[norefs]{refcheck}
\begin{document}
Why?
\label{stuff}
Because \autopageref{stuff}
\end{document}
```

The \autopageref command doesn't work.  Is there some wizardry akin to [Making refcheck work with cleveref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87610) I should use?

edit: even a comment like "I have no clue" would be appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[verbose,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[norefs]{refcheck}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\autopageref}{\@ifstar{\@autopagereffstar}{\@autopagereffnostar}}

\newcommand*{\@autopagereffstar}[1]{\HyRef@autopagerefname \pageref{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@autopagereffnostar}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\HyRef@autopagerefname \pageref{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Why?
\label{stuff2}
\label{stuff}
Because \autopageref{stuff}

\end{document}
```

This is the log:

```
Package: `refcheck' v1.9.1 <2013/02/14>
options: showrefs, showcites, msgs, chckunlbld

Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `stuff2' on input line 14.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)
[1] (./test.aux) )
Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

This is the result I get:
[image]

Using the workaround proposed in the link provided by @Naphaneal:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[verbose,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[norefs]{refcheck}


\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{refcheck}
  {%
    \@ifundefined{hyperref}{}{%
      \let\T@ref@orig\T@ref%
      \def\T@ref#1{\T@ref@orig{#1}\wrtusdrf{#1}}%
      \let\@refstar@orig\@refstar%
      \def\@refstar#1{\@refstar@orig{#1}\wrtusdrf{#1}}
      \DeclareRobustCommand\ref{\@ifstar\@refstar\T@ref}%
    }%
  }{}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
Why?
\label{stuff2}
\label{stuff}
Because \autopageref{stuff}

\end{document}
```

this is what I get:

```
Package: `refcheck' v1.9.1 <2013/02/14>
options: showrefs, showcites, msgs, chckunlbld

Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `stuff2' on input line 25.


Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `stuff' on input line 26.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `*' on page 1 undefined on input line 27.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)
[1] (./test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )
Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

and this is the document produced

[image]

Hope this will help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that page is wrong.  I admit that your example fixes the immediate problem, but the side effect is that refcheck no longer works.  That is, it no longer warns about unused labels.

Comment: I've edited the answer: you were right.

Comment: Wow.  After seeing so many magic incantations on this site, your solution is beautifully simple.  Considering I don't need the * forms of the commands, your solution collapses to `\def\autopageref#1{page~\pagref{#1}}`.  As far as I can tell though, your * form is not right: it still creates a hyperlink (but only for the page number, and not the word page).  Actually, the non-starred form technically creates a nested hyperlink, but I guess it does no harm.

Comment: Edit time out expired: I should have said it collapses to `\def#1{\hyperref[#1]{page~\pageref{#1}}}`

Comment: There's a timeout before I can award the bounty.  Leave a comment here if I forget.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274822/100482) refcheck disrepects hyperref on certain levels. Also there is a workaround provided which might help in your case.

Comment: Nope, doesn't help.  Thanks though.