# Workaround for refcheck with subcaptions

Tags: subcaption, incompatibility, refcheck

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273970/conflict-refcheck-subcaption-packages-for-label-with-underscores) mentions a conflict between `refcheck`, `subcaption` and `hyperref`, and proposes a patch to help deal with some issues due to `hyperref`.

I would like to know if there is a workaround for the issue with `refcheck` and `subcaption`, in that `refcheck` warns about unused labels due to the `sub@` prefix.

For instance, in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}
Figure \ref{fig:1a}, inside Figure \ref{fig:1}.

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \caption{A subcaption}
    \label{fig:1a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{A caption}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Both labels `fig:1` and `fig:1a` are referenced, but `refcheck` still reports:

```
Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `sub@fig:1a' on input line 12.
```

Is there a way to avoid the warning?

Answer (score 2):

This redefines the subcaption label command to always report the dummy label "sub@label" as used.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@subcaption@@label\subcaption@@label
\def\subcaption@@label#1#2{\usedref{sub@#2}\orig@subcaption@@label{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Figure \ref{fig:1a}, inside Figure \ref{fig:1}.

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \caption{A subcaption}
    \label{fig:1a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{A caption}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```