# Print pages with refs

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

> Is there a simple way to print page-numbers that contain `\ref{something}` next to each `\label{something}`?

(For a long time I am working on a long text, and want to know maybe some statements are not longer needed.)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but simply issuing `\ref` directives after each and every `\label` directive won't tell you whether the item being cross-reference in this manner are also cross-referenced elsewhere in the document. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve,.

Comment: @Mico right --- it was not clear --- it is fixed now, sorry.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How can I get LaTeX to warn about unreferenced figures and unused labels in general?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25742/how-can-i-get-latex-to-warn-about-unreferenced-figures-and-unused-labels-in-gene)

Comment: @HenriMenke --- it is a different question.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin From what I understand it's the same, which indicates that your question is unclear.  Maybe you should try to do a better job at stating your problem in the future.

Comment: @HenriMenke I do not see a way to make it more clear and it seems that refcheck does not do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

One option to check the label-reference correspondence is `showlabels`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{showlabels}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 \showlabels{ref}
 \renewcommand{\showlabelfont}{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
 Hello  \label{foo}  world.  
\section{bah}
Hello word (see section \ref{foo})
\end{document}
```

To find references without labels, simply use `hyperref` to notice easily if there are linked red text (reference with label)  or alternatively search for the `??` symbols in the document (reference without label). For the opposite (labels without any reference) you can use `refcheck`, that also show labels but those unused labels are highlighted with interrogation signs: Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcheck}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
 Hello  \label{foo}  world. % label with ref
\section{bah}
Hello word (see section \ref{foo}) % ref with label 
\section{baz}
\label{baz} % label without ref 
Hello word 
\section{whatever}\label{xyz} 
Hello word  \ref{whatever} % ref without label
\section{xyz}\label{xyz} 
Hello word (see section \ref{xyz})
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, see the `.log` file!

For instance, if you add `\ref{baz}` without the corresponding \label{baz}, you will see some like:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `baz' on page 1 undefined on input line 12.
...
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

It warns you also of duplicates labels:

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `xyz' multiply defined.
```

Whereas `showlabels` and `refcheck` simply show the labels twice, but it  could be hard to notice that are duplicates in a large document.

*Edit*

To list the pages numbers where each label and reference is, you can use the `todonotes` package, but this say noting about if three are unused label or orphan references:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\let\oldref\ref
\let\oldlabel\label
\renewcommand\ref[1]{\todo[fancyline,color=cyan!30]{R: #1}\oldref{#1}}
\renewcommand\label[1]{\todo[fancyline,color=red!30]{L: #1}\oldlabel{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
 Hello  \label{foo}  world. % label with ref
\section{bah}
Hello word (see section \ref{foo}) % ref with label
\section{baz}
\label{baz} % label without ref 
Hello word 
\section{whatever}\label{xyz} 
Hello word  \ref{whatever} % ref without label
\section{xyz}\label{xyz} 
Hello word (see section \ref{xyz})

\listoftodos[List of labels and references]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I updated my question (it was not formulated sufficiently clear, sorry).

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Still it is not clear for me what you want exactly, bur see if the added to the answer gets closer.

Comment: I simply want a list of page-numbers prineted next to each label --- those pages that contain refs.