# Removing unused labels

Tags: labels

I'm trying to remove unused labels from my latex document. I realize that this question has been [addressed before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25742/how-can-i-get-latex-to-warn-about-unreferenced-figures-and-unused-labels-in-gene). However, it doesn't answer my query, because the package `refcheck` is not compatible with `cleverer`, which is what I have used in my document. Hence, `recheck` is declaring all labels unused in my document.

EDIT:
The solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87610/making-refcheck-work-with-cleveref), written for the explicit purpose of making `refcheck` compatible with `cleveref`, doesn't work for me either. Labels for theorems and sections are recognized, but labels for equations are not.

An example from my code would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1} 
a=b
\end{equation}
Refer to \cref{eq1}
\end{document}
```

`refcheck` claims that that eq1 is an unused label.

Comment: Did you check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87610/making-refcheck-work-with-cleveref as well?

Comment: I hadn't. I just used the method explained there, and it still is not working for me. I am getting error messages for labels that I have used in the document.

Comment: Then please add the code for a small but complete document to your question with one or two labels and the `\refcheckize` parts from the other question and mention which error messages you get with that document.

Comment: @Marjin- I've added more context.

Comment: @fierydemon: are you looking for a solution employing latex-specific tools? Otherwise there's always the option to grep \ref (and the like) with your latex editor or a good text editor would do; a couple of regex searches would do...

Comment: @fierydemon your update is helpful (mentioning that the problem is specifically with equations) but still your question would be much easier to answer if you can add a small document (with some equation labels and references) that allows to reproduce the problem easily.

Comment: @Marijn- Thank you. I have now added a model snippet of code.

Comment: `refcheck` is basically stale since 2004. The author has had many years to upgrade it in order to support `cleveref`, but doesn't seem interested in doing it.

Comment: @fierydemon -- The requested code should begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.   That way, no guessing is necessary on the part of potential helpers.

Comment: If I apply `\refcheckize{\cref}` as suggested in my answer to the linked question, I have no problem.

Comment: - What is that "cleverer" you mentioned in your question?
- If you use `\cref`, you should have a `\usepackage{cleveref}` in the preamble.
- If you want to use the `refcheck` package, you need a `\usepackage{refcheck}` in the preamble.
- `\refcheckize{\cref}` from egreg's answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87610 makes `refcheck` aware of `\cref` (as pointed out in egreg's comment).