# Use \showlabel package with newcommand \loadnote

Tags: footnotes, labels, showlabels

Inside my `main.tex` I inserted a function called `\loadnote` which refers to an external file `notepie.tex` in which are considered the footnotes ([with reference to this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454073/foonotes-in-external-page)) .

```
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\newcommand{\loadnote}[1]{%
    \ExecuteMetaData[notepie.tex]{notes#1}%
}
```

I have repeatedly the following error :

```
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of (pdf)latex: Latex found
3 multiply defined reference(s)
```

and in the search [discovered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8877/warning-there-were-multiply-defined-labels) a convenient package `\usepackage{showlabels}` that allows viewing the position of footnotes and references to equations.

I would like to understand if it was possible to implement the changes regarding the footed notes written with the command `\loadnote{}`.

for example :

1.file notepie.tex:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}

\begin{document}
%<*notes004>
\footnote{La mia footnotes è questa.}
%</notes004>

\end{document}
```

2.in the main.tex file :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\newcommand{\loadnote}[1]{%
    \ExecuteMetaData[notepie.tex]{notes#1}%
}

\begin{document}

Se ho necessità di riferirmi ad una nota\loadnote{004},mentre la mia
equazione : $\tau = \mu\,\dot{\theta}{t}$\label{eq080}
\end{document}
```

the `\loadnote` is not a `\label`, I would like to know if it is possible to implement something to make sure that the lateral reference to the note is highlighted

thanks very much :)

[image]

Comment: yes probably you just need `\SK@def \loadnote` something.... A small test document showing \loadnote use would help answer the quesion

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if I enter `\SK@def `,  I have many errors and the file is not compiled

Comment: that's what I meant by "something".  showlabels lets you use `\SK@def` to hook into existing commands but the details depend on the command. you need `\SK@def\loadnote#1{.....}`  where a small test file would help test what the .... has to be. (I see you added one thanks, I'll look in a bit)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do not understand how to insert `SK@def`, in the command `\newcommand{\loadnote}[1]{%
    \ExecuteMetaData[notepie.tex]{notes#1}%
}`, because if I insert, I get errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This just hooks the `\ref` `showkeys` styling on to `\loadnote`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showkeys}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\newcommand{\loadnote}[1]{%
    \ExecuteMetaData[notepie.tex]{notes#1}%
}
\makeatletter
  \SK@def\loadnote#1{\SK@\SK@@ref{#1}\SK@loadnote{#1}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Se ho necessità di riferirmi ad una nota\loadnote{004},mentre la mia
equazione : $\tau = \mu\,\dot{\theta}{t}$\label{eq080}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the solution is excellent and very useful when mentioning the quations of which I often forget the position. I will have to read about this package. I am too new to latex and I often encounter difficulties in apparently trivial aspects

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use the `\showlabels` command of the `showlabels` package (which is a distinct package from `showkeys`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\newcommand{\loadnote}[1]{%
X#1X%  \ExecuteMetaData[notepie.tex]{notes#1}%
}

\usepackage{showlabels}
\showlabels{loadnote} % handle \loadnote like \label

\begin{document}

Se ho necessità di riferirmi ad una nota\loadnote{004},mentre la mia
equazione : $\tau = \mu\,\dot{\theta}{t}$\label{eq080}
\end{document}
```

Example output below.

[image: Example output]

Comment: Thanks. never stop learning. also your solution is very interesting and I find it very tidy.